# Modifier Keys not working for swapping Option/Command on external USB Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have been using the `Modifier Keys` option for a few years. It is however **not working on Sierra** for *external keyboards*.

The screenshot shows the configuration:

[image]

I have exited `System Preferences` and only on Sierra this does not take effect.  The laptop has been rebooted a few times as well: still no change.

I have tried this for several external keyboards from different manufacturers and on two different Sierra laptops.

Anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Karabiner Elements` to the rescue:

[image]

***This*** actually works!